# Creating an array of arrays without any duplication Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, typescript

Javascript newbie here :) I want to achieve sth but can't figure it out.

Here is my data .

```
<pre>
[
  [
    {
      "id": 2759178563,
      "title": "Ergonomic Paper Computer",
      "handle": "ergonomic-paper-computer",
      "body_html": "Enable turn-key infrastructures",
      "published_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:49-04:00",
      "created_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:49-04:00",
      "updated_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:49-04:00",
      "vendor": "Schinner Inc",
      "product_type": "Computer",
      "tags": [
        "Computer",
        "Ergonomic",
        "Paper"
      ],
      "variants": [
        {
          "id": 8041863299,
          "title": "White",
          "option1": "White",
          "option2": null,
          "option3": null,
          "price": "67.25",
          "grams": 5145,
          "compare_at_price": null,
          "sku": "",
          "requires_shipping": true,
          "taxable": true,
          "position": 1,
          "product_id": 2759178563,
          "created_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:49-04:00",
          "updated_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:49-04:00",
          "available": true,
          "featured_image": null
        },
        {
          "id": 8041863363,
          "title": "Mint green",
          "option1": "Mint green",
          "option2": null,
          "option3": null,
          "price": "29.58",
          "grams": 6860,
          "compare_at_price": null,
          "sku": "",
          "requires_shipping": true,
          "taxable": true,
          "position": 2,
          "product_id": 2759178563,
          "created_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:49-04:00",
          "updated_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:49-04:00",
          "available": true,
          "featured_image": null
        },
        {
          "id": 8041863491,
          "title": "Yellow",
          "option1": "Yellow",
          "option2": null,
          "option3": null,
          "price": "54.19",
          "grams": 6045,
          "compare_at_price": null,
          "sku": "",
          "requires_shipping": true,
          "taxable": true,
          "position": 3,
          "product_id": 2759178563,
          "created_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:49-04:00",
          "updated_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:49-04:00",
          "available": true,
          "featured_image": null
        },
        {
          "id": 8041863555,
          "title": "Blue",
          "option1": "Blue",
          "option2": null,
          "option3": null,
          "price": "22.88",
          "grams": 9526,
          "compare_at_price": null,
          "sku": "",
          "requires_shipping": true,
          "taxable": true,
          "position": 4,
          "product_id": 2759178563,
          "created_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:49-04:00",
          "updated_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:49-04:00",
          "available": true,
          "featured_image": null
        }
      ],
      "images": [
        {
          "id": 5642046019,
          "created_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:49-04:00",
          "position": 1,
          "updated_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:49-04:00",
          "product_id": 2759178563,
          "variant_ids": [],
          "src": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1000/7970/products/Ergonomic_20Paper_20Computer.png?v=1443055909"
        }
      ],
      "options": [
        {
          "name": "Title",
          "position": 1,
          "values": [
            "White",
            "Mint green",
            "Yellow",
            "Blue"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2759192387,
      "title": "Heavy Duty Concrete Keyboard",
      "handle": "heavy-duty-concrete-keyboard",
      "body_html": "Strategize synergistic e-markets",
      "published_at": "2015-09-23T20:52:07-04:00",
      "created_at": "2015-09-23T20:52:07-04:00",
      "updated_at": "2015-09-23T20:52:07-04:00",
      "vendor": "Stiedemann and Sons",
      "product_type": "Keyboard",
      "tags": [
        "Concrete",
        "Duty",
        "Heavy",
        "Keyboard"
      ],
      "variants": [
        {
          "id": 8041883779,
          "title": "Magenta",
          "option1": "Magenta",
          "option2": null,
          "option3": null,
          "price": "14.20",
          "grams": 3030,
          "compare_at_price": null,
          "sku": "",
          "requires_shipping": true,
          "taxable": true,
          "position": 1,
          "product_id": 2759192387,
          "created_at": "2015-09-23T20:52:07-04:00",
          "updated_at": "2015-09-23T20:52:07-04:00",
          "available": true,
          "featured_image": null
        }
      ],
      "images": [
        {
          "id": 5642056899,
          "created_at": "2015-09-23T20:52:07-04:00",
          "position": 1,
          "updated_at": "2015-09-23T20:52:07-04:00",
          "product_id": 2759192387,
          "variant_ids": [],
          "src": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1000/7970/products/Heavy_20Duty_20Concrete_20Keyboard.png?v=1443055927"
        }
      ],
      "options": [
        {
          "name": "Title",
          "position": 1,
          "values": [
            "Magenta"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": 2759168323,
      "title": "Awesome Cotton Computer",
      "handle": "awesome-cotton-computer-1",
      "body_html": "Brand synergistic applications",
      "published_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:24-04:00",
      "created_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:24-04:00",
      "updated_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:24-04:00",
      "vendor": "Hills Group",
      "product_type": "Computer",
      "tags": [
        "Awesome",
        "Computer",
        "Cotton"
      ],
      "variants": [
        {
          "id": 8041841795,
          "title": "Black",
          "option1": "Black",
          "option2": null,
          "option3": null,
          "price": "2.05",
          "grams": 1906,
          "compare_at_price": null,
          "sku": "",
          "requires_shipping": true,
          "taxable": true,
          "position": 1,
          "product_id": 2759168323,
          "created_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:24-04:00",
          "updated_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:24-04:00",
          "available": true,
          "featured_image": null
        },
        {
          "id": 8041841859,
          "title": "Orchid",
          "option1": "Orchid",
          "option2": null,
          "option3": null,
          "price": "10.78",
          "grams": 4970,
          "compare_at_price": null,
          "sku": "",
          "requires_shipping": true,
          "taxable": true,
          "position": 2,
          "product_id": 2759168323,
          "created_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:24-04:00",
          "updated_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:24-04:00",
          "available": true,
          "featured_image": null
        },
        {
          "id": 8041841923,
          "title": "Tan",
          "option1": "Tan",
          "option2": null,
          "option3": null,
          "price": "50.54",
          "grams": 6738,
          "compare_at_price": null,
          "sku": "",
          "requires_shipping": true,
          "taxable": true,
          "position": 3,
          "product_id": 2759168323,
          "created_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:24-04:00",
          "updated_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:24-04:00",
          "available": true,
          "featured_image": null
        },
        {
          "id": 8041841987,
          "title": "Teal",
          "option1": "Teal",
          "option2": null,
          "option3": null,
          "price": "91.51",
          "grams": 8718,
          "compare_at_price": null,
          "sku": "",
          "requires_shipping": true,
          "taxable": true,
          "position": 4,
          "product_id": 2759168323,
          "created_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:24-04:00",
          "updated_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:24-04:00",
          "available": true,
          "featured_image": null
        },
        {
          "id": 8041842051,
          "title": "Gold",
          "option1": "Gold",
          "option2": null,
          "option3": null,
          "price": "8.24",
          "grams": 194,
          "compare_at_price": null,
          "sku": "",
          "requires_shipping": true,
          "taxable": true,
          "position": 5,
          "product_id": 2759168323,
          "created_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:24-04:00",
          "updated_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:24-04:00",
          "available": true,
          "featured_image": null
        }
      ],
      "images": [
        {
          "id": 5642032131,
          "created_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:24-04:00",
          "position": 1,
          "updated_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:24-04:00",
          "product_id": 2759168323,
          "variant_ids": [],
          "src": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1000/7970/products/Awesome_20Cotton_20Computer_f74fc2a4-efa5-42ca-a3b2-36c378f1c003.png?v=1443055884"
        }
      ],
      "options": [
        {
          "name": "Title",
          "position": 1,
          "values": [
            "Black",
            "Orchid",
            "Tan",
            "Teal",
            "Gold"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2759192387,
      "title": "Heavy Duty Concrete Keyboard",
      "handle": "heavy-duty-concrete-keyboard",
      "body_html": "Strategize synergistic e-markets",
      "published_at": "2015-09-23T20:52:07-04:00",
      "created_at": "2015-09-23T20:52:07-04:00",
      "updated_at": "2015-09-23T20:52:07-04:00",
      "vendor": "Stiedemann and Sons",
      "product_type": "Keyboard",
      "tags": [
        "Concrete",
        "Duty",
        "Heavy",
        "Keyboard"
      ],
      "variants": [
        {
          "id": 8041883779,
          "title": "Magenta",
          "option1": "Magenta",
          "option2": null,
          "option3": null,
          "price": "14.20",
          "grams": 3030,
          "compare_at_price": null,
          "sku": "",
          "requires_shipping": true,
          "taxable": true,
          "position": 1,
          "product_id": 2759192387,
          "created_at": "2015-09-23T20:52:07-04:00",
          "updated_at": "2015-09-23T20:52:07-04:00",
          "available": true,
          "featured_image": null
        }
      ],
      "images": [
        {
          "id": 5642056899,
          "created_at": "2015-09-23T20:52:07-04:00",
          "position": 1,
          "updated_at": "2015-09-23T20:52:07-04:00",
          "product_id": 2759192387,
          "variant_ids": [],
          "src": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1000/7970/products/Heavy_20Duty_20Concrete_20Keyboard.png?v=1443055927"
        }
      ],
      "options": [
        {
          "name": "Title",
          "position": 1,
          "values": [
            "Magenta"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": 2759167747,
      "title": "Awesome Bronze Computer",
      "handle": "awesome-bronze-computer",
      "body_html": "Orchestrate holistic web services",
      "published_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:20-04:00",
      "created_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:20-04:00",
      "updated_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:20-04:00",
      "vendor": "Zboncak-Kemmer",
      "product_type": "Computer",
      "tags": [
        "Awesome",
        "Bronze",
        "Computer"
      ],
      "variants": [
        {
          "id": 8041840195,
          "title": "Magenta",
          "option1": "Magenta",
          "option2": null,
          "option3": null,
          "price": "56.69",
          "grams": 6035,
          "compare_at_price": null,
          "sku": "",
          "requires_shipping": true,
          "taxable": true,
          "position": 1,
          "product_id": 2759167747,
          "created_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:20-04:00",
          "updated_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:20-04:00",
          "available": true,
          "featured_image": null
        },
        {
          "id": 8041840259,
          "title": "Mint green",
          "option1": "Mint green",
          "option2": null,
          "option3": null,
          "price": "63.89",
          "grams": 9961,
          "compare_at_price": null,
          "sku": "",
          "requires_shipping": true,
          "taxable": true,
          "position": 2,
          "product_id": 2759167747,
          "created_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:20-04:00",
          "updated_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:20-04:00",
          "available": true,
          "featured_image": null
        },
        {
          "id": 8041840323,
          "title": "Maroon",
          "option1": "Maroon",
          "option2": null,
          "option3": null,
          "price": "18.76",
          "grams": 922,
          "compare_at_price": null,
          "sku": "",
          "requires_shipping": true,
          "taxable": true,
          "position": 3,
          "product_id": 2759167747,
          "created_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:20-04:00",
          "updated_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:20-04:00",
          "available": true,
          "featured_image": null
        },
        {
          "id": 8041840387,
          "title": "Salmon",
          "option1": "Salmon",
          "option2": null,
          "option3": null,
          "price": "97.60",
          "grams": 1355,
          "compare_at_price": null,
          "sku": "",
          "requires_shipping": true,
          "taxable": true,
          "position": 4,
          "product_id": 2759167747,
          "created_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:20-04:00",
          "updated_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:20-04:00",
          "available": true,
          "featured_image": null
        }
      ],
      "images": [
        {
          "id": 5642031235,
          "created_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:20-04:00",
          "position": 1,
          "updated_at": "2015-09-23T20:51:20-04:00",
          "product_id": 2759167747,
          "variant_ids": [],
          "src": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1000/7970/products/Awesome_20Bronze_20Computer.png?v=1443055880"
        }
      ],
      "options": [
        {
          "name": "Title",
          "position": 1,
          "values": [
            "Magenta",
            "Mint green",
            "Maroon",
            "Salmon"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2759192387,
      "title": "Heavy Duty Concrete Keyboard",
      "handle": "heavy-duty-concrete-keyboard",
      "body_html": "Strategize synergistic e-markets",
      "published_at": "2015-09-23T20:52:07-04:00",
      "created_at": "2015-09-23T20:52:07-04:00",
      "updated_at": "2015-09-23T20:52:07-04:00",
      "vendor": "Stiedemann and Sons",
      "product_type": "Keyboard",
      "tags": [
        "Concrete",
        "Duty",
        "Heavy",
        "Keyboard"
      ],
      "variants": [
        {
          "id": 8041883779,
          "title": "Magenta",
          "option1": "Magenta",
          "option2": null,
          "option3": null,
          "price": "14.20",
          "grams": 3030,
          "compare_at_price": null,
          "sku": "",
          "requires_shipping": true,
          "taxable": true,
          "position": 1,
          "product_id": 2759192387,
          "created_at": "2015-09-23T20:52:07-04:00",
          "updated_at": "2015-09-23T20:52:07-04:00",
          "available": true,
          "featured_image": null
        }
      ],
      "images": [
        {
          "id": 5642056899,
          "created_at": "2015-09-23T20:52:07-04:00",
          "position": 1,
          "updated_at": "2015-09-23T20:52:07-04:00",
          "product_id": 2759192387,
          "variant_ids": [],
          "src": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1000/7970/products/Heavy_20Duty_20Concrete_20Keyboard.png?v=1443055927"
        }
      ],
      "options": [
        {
          "name": "Title",
          "position": 1,
          "values": [
            "Magenta"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
]
</pre>
```

And here is my code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()

export class ShopifyService {

    /**
     * Initialization
     */
    constructor (
        private http: Http
    ) {}

    private shopifyUrl = 'app/heroes.json';

    errorMessage: string;

    /**
     * Private Methods
     */
    fetchProducts(): Promise<Response> {
        return this.http.get(this.shopifyUrl)
            .toPromise()
            .then(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        if (res.status < 200 || res.status >= 300) {
            throw new Error('Bad response status: ' + res.status);
        }
        let body = res.json();
        if (body.data) {
            return body.data;
        }
        else if (body.products) {
            return body.products;
        }
        else {
            return { };
        }
    }

    private handleError (error: any) {
        let errMsg = error.message || 'Server error';
        console.error(errMsg);
        return Promise.reject(errMsg);
    }

    private filterProducts(list, archetype) {
        var result = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (list[i].product_type === archetype) {
                result.push(list[i]);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Public Methods
     */
    public findProducts(archetypes) {
        return this.fetchProducts().then(
                products => {
                        var result = [],
                            fetchedResponse = [];

                    for (var i = 0; i < archetypes.length; i++) {
                        fetchedResponse = this.filterProducts(
                            products, archetypes[i]
                        );
                        result = result.concat(fetchedResponse);
                    }
                    return result;
                },
                error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
            )
    }

    public findSingleProductVariant() {
        var result = [],
            j = 0;

        return this.findVariants().then(
            product => {
                for (var i = 0; i < product.length; i++) {
                    // console.log(product[i]);
                }
            }
        );
        // return result;
    }

    findVariants() {
        return this.findProducts(['Computer', 'Keyboard']).then(
            products => {
                var result = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
                    if (products[i].product_type === 'Computer') {
                        for (var j = 0; j < products.length; j++) {
                            if (products[j].product_type === 'Keyboard') {
                                result.push([products[i], products[j]]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                console.log(result);
                return result;
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Until here I got to half of what. An array of two dimensional arrays (one of them is from keyboard type and another one from computer type).

It is sth like this ==>

```
[
    [
        [Computer_A],
        [Keyboard_A]
    ],
    [
        [Computer_B],
        [Keyboard_A]
    ], 
    [
        [Computer_C],
        [Keyboard_A]
    ],
]
```

Now each one of these objects have its own array of variants. I have to modify my `findSingleProductVariant` in order to go over each one of these arrays, pick a `keyboard` variant (which its array has a price field), also pick a `computer` variant and calculate the price. If the price is less than 1000, it can continue picking another keyboard and computer. But the thing is that it can't have two identical arrays. for instance we can't have sth like this.

```
[
    ['Computer_A'], ['Keyboard_A'],
    ['Computer_A'], ['Keyboard_A'],
]
```

Comment: could you please add the relevant data in **text form** to the question ?

Comment: how have some strings with numbers in it something to do with tables or lamps?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion Nina :) In my code first I am filtering certain product types and after filtering them I am only interested in their prices. I will put a portion of the real data in the question. Thanks for taking the time

Answer (score -1):

The key thing here is that you can't directly compare objects and expect relevant results, e.g.

```
['Red Lamp', 'Blue Table'] === ['Red Lamp', 'Blue Table']
```

will return false (`Array.indexOf()` also won't work as expected since it uses strict comparison).

So for an array of arrays, you will have to use two nested loops to get down to comparing primitive values.

Comment: Thanks Kama. Nested loops helped me  alot to move further but I'm still stuck but in another part :)